# Solve $\frac{1}{x} \neq \frac{1}{x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

More broadly, I'm confused about how division by zero works with the equal sign and the not equal sign. Would it be correct to say that when division by zero is found in an $=$ equation, the equation is false? Would it be correct to say that when division by zero is found in a $\neq$ equation, the equation is true?

I'm asking purely in elementary algebra, over the reals.

Addendum 1. Proof:

$$\frac{1}{x} \neq \frac{1}{x}$$
$$\neg(\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{x})$$
$$\neg(x \neq 0)$$
$$\neg\neg(x = 0)$$
$$x = 0$$

Addendum 2. Proof $\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{x}$ is false at $x = 0$:
$$\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{x}, x = 0$$
$$x \neq 0, x = 0$$
$$0 \neq 0, x = 0 \quad \text{by substitution}$$
$$\text{false}, x = 0$$

Addendum 3. To ask a more focused question, I'm aware of the standard interpretation of division by 0 as meaningless. That being said, I'm not sure where I'm going wrong in the second proof, which seems to show division by 0 in an equation to be false. What is wrong with the second proof?

Comment: If $\,x=0\,$ then the above is neither true nor false - it is *undefined*. Just because you can write $\,1/0\,$ on paper does not give it a math sense, and in fact it doesn't have any.

Comment: My understanding and interpretation is the same.  The (*real*) solution set to $\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{x}$ is the set of real numbers such that both sides of the equation are defined *and* equal to one another, which in this case would be $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ (*all nonzero real numbers*).  The solution set to $\frac{1}{x}\neq \frac{1}{x}$ would be the set of real numbers such that both sides of the equation are defined *and* are unequal to one another.  In this case, it would be the empty-set.

Comment: In more exotic contexts where we do allow division by zero (*e.g. in the extended complex numbers*) the equation would hold true for all values of $x$, (*which should make sense... the symbol $=$ is generally reserved for equivalence relations which are always reflexive, i.e. a number is always "equal" to itself.  Since $\frac{1}{x}$ on the left is the same expression as $\frac{1}{x}$ on the right, they had better be considered equal so long as they are defined*)

Comment: Division by 0 doesn't work.  period.  If division by zero is found in either an equation or inequality it's invalid.  That doesn't mean it is true or false.  Just that it is invalid garbage and you must throw everything you've done away.

Comment: $\frac 10 \ne \frac 10$ is not true.  $\frac 1x \ne \frac 1x$ is simply a contradiction with no solutions.  The statement is false for all reals where $\frac 1x$ is defined and the statement is meaningless where $\frac 1x$ is not defined.

Comment: I'm a bit annoyed you  edited in proof stating "$\frac 1x = \frac 1x$ is false when $x = 0$" nearly an hour after three people told you $\frac 1x = \frac 1x$ is *NOT* false at $x = 0$.  It is undefined and meaningless at $x =0$.  It is not false.

Comment: fleablood, I apologize if adding the proofs was incorrect stackexchange etiquette. I hoped to clarify my question based on the comments. I'm working this out as I go along. By my thinking "checking the 0 case" in basic algebra has the effect of throwing away equations with 0 in the denominator. Then after doing this you can ask if $x = 0$ and simply answer false. Everyone here is correct that in something like abstract algebra, the equation could not be constructed at all. Basic algebra seems, in a sense, more dynamic than abstract algebra.

Answer (score 2):

Excellent question.

Unfortunately, opinions on this issue differ.

One viewpoint is that division is a function $$\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}.$$ Under this viewpoint, you're not really allowed to write down $1/x$ until you already have a proof that $x$ lives in $\mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$. So $1/x \neq 1/x$ cannot be solved, because we're not even allowed to write it down. What we're allowed to write down is:

> Assume $x \neq 0$. Solve $1/x \neq 1/x$.

The solution is that, in the presence of $x \neq 0$, the condition $1/x \neq 1/x$ is equivalent to FALSE. However if we drop the $x \neq 0$, it's not a well-formed expression and we just ignore it.

That's one viewpoint. However, there's others. Classically, a partial function $X \rightarrow Y$ can be defined as an ordinary function $X \rightarrow Y\sqcup \mathbb{1}$. There's lots of things you can do with partial functions that match things you can do with ordinary functions. For example, they can be composed, and if we have partial functions $f:X \rightarrow F$ and $g:X \rightarrow G$ we can get a partial function $(f,g) : X \rightarrow F \times G$ in much the same way we can do this for ordinary functions.

This gives a very different viewpoint. In particular, we think of $1/x \neq 1/x$ as a partial function that turns a real number $X$ into an element of $\mathbb{B} \sqcup \mathbb{1},$ where $\mathbb{B}$ is the set $\{\mathrm{TRUE},\mathrm{FALSE}\}$. Ergo $\mathbb{B} \sqcup \mathbb{1}$ can be identified with the set $\{\mathrm{TRUE},\mathrm{FALSE},\mathrm{OTHER}\}$ that has a "third truthvalue" called $\mathrm{OTHER}.$ To get a "predicate" in the ordinary sense of the word, we have to choose a function from $\mathbb{B} \sqcup \mathbb{1}$ to $\mathbb{B}$. Define functions $$\Box,\Diamond : \mathbb{B} \sqcup \mathbb{1} \rightarrow \mathbb{B}$$ to act as the identity on ordinary truthvalues. The function $\Box$ will map $\mathrm{OTHER}$ to $\mathrm{FALSE}$ and the function $\Diamond$ will map $\mathrm{OTHER}$ to $\mathrm{TRUE}$.

Then $$\Box\left(\frac{1}{x} \neq \frac{1}{x}\right), \qquad \Diamond\left(\frac{1}{x} \neq \frac{1}{x}\right)$$ can be solved. The former is equivalent to FALSE and the latter is equivalent to $x=0$.

Continuing with the theme of partial functions, yet another viewpoint is that $=$ should mean [Kleene equality](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kleene+equality). I don't really agree with this, but certainly Kleene equality is useful in its own right. Here's a good exercise:

Let $\iff$ mean Kleene equality and $\Rightarrow$ mean that if the LHS is well-defined, then so too is the RHS, and they're equal. Find the following:

$$\Box\left(\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{x}\right), \qquad \Diamond\left(\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{x}\right), \qquad \frac{1}{x} \iff \frac{1}{x}, \qquad \frac{1}{x} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{x}$$

$$\Box\left(\frac{1}{1/x} = x\right), \qquad \Diamond\left(\frac{1}{1/x} = x\right), \qquad \frac{1}{1/x} \iff x, \qquad \frac{1}{1/x} \Rightarrow x$$

Comment: Going with your first viewpoint. My question then becomes: can we assume basic algebra comes with hidden assumptions about the denominators, rendering the equations meaningful at all values of x?

Comment: @krsm, different people have different opinions about such things. What we're taught in high school might differ from what we're taught at university, which might differ from what a professional mathematician thinks, which might differ from what a different professional mathematician thinks, which might differ from the conventions embedded into any particular formal system, which might differ from the conventions in some other formal system.

Comment: @krsm, also be forewarned that this community seems to be fairly petty and vindictive (especially in connection with partiality, ill-formed expressions, etc.). So, although your question is a good question, don't expect to get much love here.